# Displaying selected error messages that get generated over a period of time in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

I want to display messages as and when they get generated. I want to display only selected error messages from the array of errors that I have created. I am using `array.filter` method to filter the error messages, but that's not working. It is simply showing all the elements in the array.

Here's the service code:

```
error: any[] = [];

addError() {
    // error gets generated over a period of time
    this.error.push({ msg: 'A', statusText: 'a', status: 25 });
    this.error.push({ msg: 'B', statusText: 'b', status: 35 });
    this.error.push({ msg: 'C', statusText: 'c', status: 45 });
    this.error.push({ msg: 'D', statusText: 'd', status: 55 });
    this.error.push({ msg: 'E', statusText: 'e', status: 65 });
    this.error.push({ msg: 'F', statusText: 'f', status: 75 });

    this.error = this.error.filter(err => err.status > 45);
  }

  getErrors(): any[] {
    console.log(`in the get methog ${JSON.stringify(this.error)}`);
    return this.error;
  }
```

Here's the `parent-component` that's displaying the error messages:

```
  data: any[];

  constructor(private _error: ErrorService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._error.getErrors();
  }
```

Here's the `child-component` that generates errors:

```
addError() {
    this._info.addInfo();
  }
```

Note: This addError method is called on the click event of a button.

The issue here is that: Even though I am filtering the error array, I can see all the error messages (`A-F)` whereas I should only see `D, E and F`.

Where am I going wrong?? Do I need to use observable to achieve the desired results or I can do it with some modification to the above code?

Here's the link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcbg4j)

Comment: Write your filter code in geterror method

Comment: @MukulSharma, same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the reference.

- `ngOnInit` of  `parent-component` the `data` holds the reference of the `error` array.
- When we will do the array.filter() then `error` will hold a new reference but not updating in the `parent-component`.

**Solution** We can fix With simple modification in code without using Observable. We can use Observable to fix the problem.

**Step 1:** Add a `filteredErrors` property reader to the `ErrorService`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {

  error: any[] = [];

  addError() {
      this.error.push({ msg: 'A', statusText: 'a', status: 25 });
      this.error.push({ msg: 'B', statusText: 'b', status: 35 });
      this.error.push({ msg: 'C', statusText: 'c', status: 45 });
      this.error.push({ msg: 'D', statusText: 'd', status: 55 });
      this.error.push({ msg: 'E', statusText: 'e', status: 65 });
      this.error.push({ msg: 'F', statusText: 'f', status: 75 });
  }

  get filteredErrors() {
    return this.error.filter(err => err.status > 45);
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** Read `filteredErrors` for iterating over filtered errors. Following are the details of the `ParentComponent`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `<p *ngFor="let error of errors">
      First Name: {{ error.msg }} Last Name: {{ error.statusText }}
    </p>
    <app-child></app-child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor(public  _error: ErrorService) {}

  get errors() {
    return this._error.filteredErrors || [];
  }
}
```

For reference added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yown7y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts) code link.